# Date field: prepopulate off

Tags: datetime

When adding a new node with a date field in it, the date field is prepopulated with the current date. Is there a way to easily switch that feature off so that the date field is empty?

Comment: Not really. Controls used in Date Field does not really support being empty as the date picker would feel lost without *some* default ;) But I'm not 100% positive on that, it's just what I think I remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default-values in your Content-type > Field-settings > More settings and values > Default values, (Now, Relative, No default value) set it to "No default value".

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. First, could you use English language to take your screenshot? English is Internet's Common now, and not everybody understand German (or whatever it is in your post). All Drupal installations contains English. Second, could you show it set to "none"?

Comment: I would if i could... (and i've done it now) like i said in the answer (before editing) i had no access to a english enabled drupal-install, sure you could configure drupal to show the admin in english, but depending on the configuration you can't do that easily on the fly, at least not on a production-system... now i'm back at the devel-system and re-shot it in english. But i found it more important to give a quick helpful answer, than a perfect one after a more or less long time... and 'criscom' did understand it, what's IMO the most important part :)